# I can't find my errors in Qgis Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, error

I have a long field calculator script in QGIS and i try to find the errors and i can't find them. It is very repetitive in 3 parts. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

I ask for your help if it is possible. It has been some days i search and i can't find what's wrong. I am not a newcomer on qgis

```
if("dosemax"=80,

if(((maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe")  >= "RMSE",
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-1))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-1)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-2))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-2)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-3))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-3)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-4))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-4)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-5))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-5)*0.0625))*"dosemax"), "dosemax"))))),

if((maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe")  < "RMSE",
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-1))*"RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-1)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-2))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-2)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-3))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-3)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-4))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-4)*0.0625))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-5))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-5)*0.0625))*"dosemax"), "dosemax")))))))


or
if("dosemax"=100,

if(((maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe")  >= "RMSE",
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-1))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-1)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-2))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-2)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-3))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-3)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-4))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-4)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-5))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-5)*0.09))*"dosemax"), "dosemax"))))),

if((maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe")  < "RMSE",
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-1))*"RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-1)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-2))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-2)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-3))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-3)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-4))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-4)*0.09))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-5))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-5)*0.09))*"dosemax"), "dosemax")))))))


or
if("dosemax"=120,

if(((maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe")  >= "RMSE",
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-1))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-1)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-2))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-2)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-3))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-3)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-4))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-4)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-5))*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))),
((1-(("classe"-5)*0.08))*"dosemax"), "dosemax"))))),

if((maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe")  < "RMSE",
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-1))*"RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-1)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-2))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-2)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-3))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-3)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-4))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-4)*0.08))*"dosemax"),
if("moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (("classe"-("classe"-5))* "RMSE")),
((1-(("classe"-5)*0.08))*"dosemax"), "dosemax")))))))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the only error, but your `if((maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe") ...` are wrong. They are missing an opening parenthesis.

Comment: What is the error? :)

Comment: @Joseph maybe a parenthese or the "or" function or the "if" function and the number of attributes

Comment: It seems that your expression is equivalent to `condition1 or condition2 or condition3`. What kind of result do you expect?

Comment: @ArMoraer I have 3 main conditions (dosemax = 80 or 100 or 120) and each has 2 conditions (>=RMSE or < RMSE)  I ask him to check if the main condition is OK and if it is OK to check if the second is OK etc....

Comment: @MarcRobin Then I think that your expression would be much more easy to write and understand if you use one or several `CASE WHEN ...` statements, rather than `if`s.

Comment: @ArMoraer maybe i will try it. i prefered at first the ifs but i will try in another way. Can we do CASE WHEN in differents floors like with if inside a if ?

Comment: @MarcRobin Nested `CASE` should work, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comments between you and [ArMoraer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64955/armoraer), for you to test `CASE WHEN`:

```
CASE 
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (1*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))) 
THEN (1-("classe"-1)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (2*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-2)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (3*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-3)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (4*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-4)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (5*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-5)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (1*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-1)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (2*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-2)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (3*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-3)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (4*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-4)*0.0625)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=80 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (5*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-5)*0.0625)*"dosemax"

WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (1*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))) 
THEN (1-("classe"-1)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (2*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-2)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (3*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-3)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (4*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-4)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (5*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-5)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (1*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-1)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (2*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-2)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (3*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-3)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (4*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-4)*0.09)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=100 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (5*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-5)*0.09)*"dosemax"

WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (1*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe")))) 
THEN (1-("classe"-1)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (2*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-2)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (3*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-3)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (4*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-4)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"  >= "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (5*((maximum("moyennemea") - minimum("moyennemea")/"classe"))))
THEN (1-("classe"-5)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (1*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-1)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (2*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-2)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (3*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-3)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (4*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-4)*0.08)*"dosemax"
WHEN "dosemax"=120 AND (maximum("moyennemea")-minimum("moyennemea"))/"classe"   < "RMSE" AND "moyennemea" < (minimum("moyennemea") + (5*"RMSE"))
THEN (1-("classe"-5)*0.08)*"dosemax"

ELSE "dosemax"

END
```